# I can't translate 天吼

Tags: translation, kanji, definitions, chinese

Context: Mecha anime soundtrack.

I know that 天 is akin to "heavenly," but I've never seen 吼 before, and I can't find a translation -- or even another use in Japanese -- online at all. In traditional Chinese it means "roar," and all-in-all that makes some contextual sense, but I'm not comfortable just mashing the two together like that. Is this actually a Chinese title in the middle of a Japanese soundtrack, or is this a kanji I need to be educated on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

吼 means something along the lines of **cry** or **roar**.  So think of it as a noise like 鳴【なる】.

- 吼【ほ】える = to bark, to howl
- 咆吼【ほうこう】= a howl, cry (alternative to 咆哮)
- 獅子吼【ししく】 = lion’s roar
- 帆猿【ほえざる】 = Howler Monkey
- 吼【ほ】え声【ごえ】= a bark, a howl

So I guess it’s a term that’s made up for an anime or game. You said it was used in a song? It sometimes happens they coin new words in those (especially in anime and game related music). For the pronunciation you’d have to listen to the song though. If I had to make a guess, it would be **てんこう**.

The meaning, however, is straightforward: **heavenly roar**.

edited: provided more examples.

Comment: Thank you! That was my impression, but I didn't want to only go off of a translation from Chinese. Thanks so much for showing me what it means. It was an instrumental song, of all things!

Comment: @SilverbackNet, Yeah that’s also possible. Happy to help. Song titles are the worst to translate sometimes. 

Comment: I just noticed that ほえる is just "howl." This is leading me down a rabbit hole of etymology for whether the word is shared or the sound is universal. BTW, do you mind if I update wiktionary with your examples?

Comment: @SilverbackNet , I don’t mind. Knowledge has to be shared.

Comment: I believe the reading for 吼え声 should be ほえごえ

Comment: @Leebo , Yes. Sorry about that. I use a kana keyboard on my phone so I forgot to tap the button to generate tenten